# Python3 tkinter for game board

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have written a chess code that is text based in `Python 3.4.3`. I print `NumPy` array consisting of chess piece identifications to the command line(standard output). However, I would like to designate a GUI for it, is it easy to do so in `tkinter`? My chessboard output is as follows:

```
['Rb' '0 ' 'Bb' 'Qb' 'Kb' 'Bb' 'Nb' 'Rb']
['Pb' 'Pb' 'Pb' 'Pb' '0 ' 'Pb' 'Pb' 'Pb']
['0 ' '0 ' 'Nb' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ']
['0 ' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ' 'Pb' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ']
['0 ' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ' 'Pw' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ']
['0 ' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ' '0 ' 'Qw' '0 ' '0 ']
['Pw' 'Pw' 'Pw' 'Pw' '0 ' 'Pw' 'Pw' 'Pw']
['Rw' 'Nw' 'Bw' '0 ' 'Kw' 'Bw' 'Nw' 'Rw']
```

Where R:Rook, N:Knight, B:Bishop, Q:Queen, K:King, P:Pawn and the lower case letters denote the corresponding color. I virtually have no experience with designing a GUI and open to try other packages than tkinter?

The code was too long so I pasted all of them on `pastebin.com` here is the link http://pastebin.com/Lt03PWkN

Comment: yes, it is easy to do so in tkinter. Is that all you want to know?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes that is all I want to know and I am experimenting it myself, please see my latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would set it up the chess board and give each little square on the board a value or variable to go along with it like

`sq1="empty"`

give each square on the board a value like that going up 1

once a pice on the board moves up the appropriate amount than take away the value of the tile and move it to the new tile the piece is on

to figure out what the piece is able to do make a new variable called x and y for each piece add to y and x to figure out what it can do.

so yes it is possible but hard

Comment: However, I could not manage to have Tkinter displayed continously and upgraded when a piece is moved. How can I do that?